# How to style react-select component

Tags: reactjs, postcss, react-select, react-css-modules

I'm struggling to style `react-select` when attempting to bundle `css` in my `jsx`.

I can style `react-select` if I include its `dist/react-select.css` file in  my `index.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./react-select.css">
```

However, I don't want the overhead of having to distribute that extra file.

Here's a basic overview of my current attempt to bundle the `css` within my `jsx` (I've tried a few other approaches, too). In `theme.jsx`:

```
import rTSelect from '../stylesheets/react-select.css'
export {rTSelect}
```

In `form.jsx`:

```
import classNames from 'classnames/bind'
import Select from 'react-select'
import {rTSelect} from './theme'

class MySelect extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)        
    this.className = {}
  }

  _handleChange (value) {
    this.props.parentFunc(value)
  }

  render () {
    let cx = classNames.bind(rTSelect)
    this.className = cx({Select: true})
    return (
      <Tooltip title={this.props.tip} position="top">
        <Select
          className={this.className}
          placeholder={this.props.placeHolder}
          searchable={this.props.searchable}
          disabled={this.props.disabled}
          clearable={this.props.clearable}
          options={this.props.selections}
          value={this.props.selection}
          onChange={this._handleChange.bind(this)}
        />
      </Tooltip>
    )
  }
}
```

This approach seems to work for other components (although, I'm not having to use `classnames/bind`).

I will admit I don't use `react` too often - I learn enough to make it work, so I'm not that proficient and only have a vague idea of what's going on with `css`. Anyway, I've checked my `package.json`, and along the way, I seem to have found the need to install the following `css` related `dependencies`:

```
react-css-modules
react-css-themr
normalize.css
postcss
postcss-cssnext
postcss-modules-values
```

And `devdependencies`:

```
css-loader
postcss-import
postcss-loader
style-loader
```

Any help very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got react-select to pick up styling by doing this in `form.jsx`:

```
import '!style-loader!css-loader!react-select/dist/react-select.css'
```

And then just rendering as usual:

```
render () {
    return (
      <Tooltip title={this.props.tip} position="top">
        <Select
          placeholder={this.props.placeHolder}
          searchable={this.props.searchable}
          disabled={this.props.disabled}
          clearable={this.props.clearable}
          options={this.props.selections}
          value={this.props.selection}
          onChange={this._handleChange.bind(this)}
        />
      </Tooltip>
    )
  }
}
```

I'm not overly certain *why* it works, though! In fact, I'm not overly certain what that `import` syntax does. Here's my guess: The `!` is acting a bit like a 'nix pipe; so here, I'm piping the output from `style-loader` to `css-loader` which then does the actual importing. So for `react-select`, I'm kinda undoing whatever it is `style-loader` does for me in my `webpack` config'. In other words, `react-select` doesn't like `style-loader`. Right?